# Multiple match clauses in alertmanager config?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

In the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route), it says that we can add a set of match clauses under `match:`. It says literally:

> A set of equality matchers an alert has to fulfill to match the node.
>
> match:
> [ <labelname>: <labelvalue>, ... ]

But it doesn't tell us how to actually provide there multiple matchers. Neither does it tell us if these matchers and ANDed or ORd.

So my two questions are:

1. How does one properly provide multiple match clauses for a receiver?
2. Will these match clauses be ANDed or ORd?

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use the deprecated version?

Comment: I need to provide the configSecret myself, and it only seems to take the deprecated version.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How does one properly provide multiple match clauses for a receiver?

I would expect following to work:

```yaml
match:
  label1: value1
  lavel2: value2
```

> 2. Will these match clauses be ANDed or ORd?

All clauses have to match, i.e. the clauses are ANDed.

Answer (score 1):

Just confirming that you can add multiple match clauses, which are ANDed. Means all clauses have to match.

Like for example:

```yaml
routes:
    - matchers:
        - name: severity
          value: warning
        - name: foo
          value: bar
      receiver: slack
      repeatInterval: 24h
    - matchers:
        - name: severity
          value: warning
      receiver: msteams
      repeatInterval: 24h
```

In the example above, both clauses watch on the same severity but the alert message will only be send to the slack receiver, when also the label `foo=bar` matches. Otherwise the alert will only be send to the msteams receiver.